# Сумма значений в столбце таблицы mysql по заданному условию

Tags: php, mysql, суммирование

Здравствуйте.
Есть таблица результатов тестирования, каждая строчка содержит информацию, сколько тот или иной юзер набрал в том или ином тесте.

```
id | user_id | test_id | result
1  | 1       | 1       | 15    
2  | 3       | 1       | 10
3  | 1       | 2       | 5
4  | 3       | 3       | 5 
5  | 2       | 1       | 10
6  | 1       | 3       | 10
```

Требуется подсчитать, каков общий результат по всем тестам у каждого пользователя, то есть, вывести (согласно приведенному выше примеру) следующее:

```
user 1  = 30
user 2  = 10
user 3  = 15
```

Как это сосчитать, и вывести? Можно ли считать прямо в sql-запросе? Или сначала собрать всю таблицу в массив, и его как-то дополнительно обработать?

Или проще дополнительную таблицу создать, в которую суммировать все набранные пользователем баллы?

Заранее спасибо.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский group by user_id выдает только одно максимальное (потому, что desc, если asc, то минимальное) значение для каждого пользователя, а остальные скрывает, или я чтото не так понял

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT user_id, SUM(result) AS user_sum FROM `table` GROUP BY user_id
```

`GROUP BY` - используется для определения групп выходных строк, к которым могут применяться агрегатные функции (COUNT, MIN, MAX, AVG и SUM) **[больше информации...](http://www.sql-tutorial.ru/ru/book_group_by_clause.html)** и **[доки](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html)**